# QKeyEvent with multiple shift/control modifiers

Tags: qt, hid, qkeyevent

I have a USB device with 6 buttons that I am trying to use with my app. The document for the device lists the key mappings for each button. One of these button for example is said to map to Ctrl+Shift+F20.

Coding this though does not work:

The code I have inherited is:

```
void devControl::processKeyRelease(QKeyEvent *ke)
{
    int key = ke->key();

    if (ke->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier &&
        ke->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
    {
         if ( key = Qt::Key_F20 )
         {
             // Do somethings
         }
    }
.
.
}
```

I used USBLyzer ( http://www.usblyzer.com/ ) and evtest on Linux ( https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-evtest/ ) to check the data/keys being sent and found for this button the following:

[image]

The raw value is `01 03 00 6F 00 00 00 00 00`.

Looking at all the buttons data, they all exhibit the same behaviour in the the modifiers are repeated.

My thought is to try this:

```
    if (ke->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier &&
        ke->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier &&
        ke->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier &&
        ke->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
```

But is this correct? I am waiting to try this in the morning when I go back in to work, but would appreciate advice form anyone who has seen this before.

**EDIT 1**

The above did not make a difference.
I added some more debug as follows:

```
if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
    QKeyEvent *eKey = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e);
    qDebug() << "Key PRESS event " << eKey->modifiers() << Qt::Key(eKey->key());

}
```

The results were:

```
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Control)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Control)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Control)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Control)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Control)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Shift)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Shift)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Shift)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Shift)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_Shift)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_F20)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_F20)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_F20)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_F20)
Key PRESS event  QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifiers>(ShiftModifier|ControlModifier) Qt::Key(Key_F20)
```

I need a way to know when the whole event or key combinations start and end for sure. Then I can accumulate the presses over the whole event and decide what button was pressed.

**EDIT 2**

Decided to handle this by adding booleans to record when key Control, Shift or Alt are detected, and when a non-modifier is detected assume we have all the keys (true for this device) then execute the appropriate logic.

This works now.

bool _controlPressed;
bool _shiftPressed;
bool _altPressed;
bool _action_Completed;

These are set to false when a new button press is detected.

Then each time OnKeyRelease is called:

```
if (key == Qt::Key_Control ){
    _action_Completed = false; // We expect one or more key
    _controlPressed = true;
    return;
}  
if (key == Qt::Key_Shift ) {
    _action_Completed = false;  // We expect one or more key
    _shiftPressed = true;
    return;
}
if (key == Qt::Key_Alt ){
    _action_Completed = false; // We expect one or more key
    _altPressed = true;
    return;
}
if ( _controlPressed && _shiftPressed && _altPressed  && ! _action_Completed )
{
    if (! mappedKey( key)) {
        return;
    }

    doCtrlShiftAlt( key);
    return;
}
if ( _controlPressed && _shiftPressed  && ! _action_Completed )
{
    if (! mappedKey( key)) {
        return;
    }

    doCtrlShift( key);
    return;
}
if (  _shiftPressed   && ! _action_Completed )
{
    if (! mappedKey( key)) {
        return;
    }

    doShift( key);
    return;
}

if (! mappedKey( key)) {
    return;
}

if (  ! _action_Completed )
{
    doNoMod( key);
}
```

Comment: I think that coding your proposed "if" statement would be equivalent to coding "if A and B and A and B" which the compiler would optimise to just "if A and B". I would do some good old-fashioned println debugging in processKeyRelease to find out exactly what it is seeing when the device presses the keys.

Comment: Thanks aja. As you expected my if check change made no difference. I've added some more debug.

Comment: The QKeyEvent object apparently contains a count value which is the number of keys involved in the event. Perhaps you could test for 3. I'm no Qt expert but it might be worth a shot.